# Why doesn't the move constructor get called in the fill_n

Tags: multithreading, c++11, stl-algorithm

The error I get says that the `fill_n` line below is trying to use the deleted copy constructor: why is it not trying to use the move constructor?  I tried wrapping it in a `std::move` but that didn't help.

```
std::vector< std::thread > workers;
workers.reserve( 10 );
std::fill_n( std::back_inserter( workers ), 10, std::thread( []{ std::cout << "thread\n"; } ) );
```

However, if I change the `fill_n` line to

```
for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
{
  workers.push_back( std::thread( []{ std::cout << "thread\n"; } ) );
}
```

that works fine.  I thought these were essentially the same as I've done changes from the one to the other before in somewhat similar looking code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the line

```
std::fill_n( std::back_inserter( workers ), 10, std::thread( []{ std::cout << "thread\n"; } ) );
```

there is a single temporary `std::thread` instance created, and `fill_n` tries to make 10 copies of it to fill `workers`. You cannot **move** an object to make many **copies** - it just doesn't make any sense.

What you want is probably `std::generate_n`:

```
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(workers), 10, [] {
    return std::thread([] { std::cout << "thread\n"; });
});
```